# Python multiple list comprehensions containing ranges of tuples in one list

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I need a list like this:

```
[(16,2), (14,3), (15,3), (16,3), (18,3), (19,3), (12,4), (13,4), (14,4)]
```

But much, much longer. There are certain **really large range patterns** in this list, but also **irregularities**. So it would be unfeasible to write down *all* tuples, but I can't make a simple listcomp either.

I wanted to use:

```
[(16,2), (x,3) for x in range(14,19), (x,4) for x in range(12,14)]
```

But according to the docs, `[x, y for ...]` is not allowed, and my example is interpreted as an unparenthesed tuple of 2 parenthesed tuples, instead of a tuple followed by a list comprehension.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
[(16, 2)] + [(x,3) for x in range(14,19)] + [(x,4) for x in range(12,14)]
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm!

The lists are like pixel coordinates, and a few of these lists form a pixelated rhombus with 16 on y=2, broadening by 2 pixels until y=12, where it gets smaller again. Any way of making it even more condensed?

Answer (score 1):

From your question is not clear if you're trying to increase the second index at every new range.

If that's the case you could put all the ranges in a list and use [`itertools.count()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
from itertools import count
indexes = [(16,17), (14, 20), (12, 15)]

[(x, n) for i,n in zip(indexes,count(2)) for x in range(*i)]
```

Which give exactly:

```
[(16, 2), (14, 3), (15, 3), (16, 3), (17, 3), (18, 3), (19, 3), (12, 4), (13, 4), (14, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create separate lists and then append them to each other.

```
a = [(16, 2)]
b = [(x, 3) for x in range(14, 19)]
c = [(x, 4) for x in range(12, 15)]
a.extend(b)
a.extend(c)
```